# standalone shell script vs. shell function?

Tags: bash, function, shell

For example, I'd like to write a bash shell script to do rotating backups with `rsync`. Should I put it as a standalone script file (`backup.sh`) or wrap it in a function (`backup`)? As a script file, I can just run it `bash backup.sh`. As a function, I can put it in a file such as `foo.sh` and source it whenever I login, then I can simply run `backup` as a command to backup my files. The question is, what are the cons and pros for the two strategies?

Or more generally, I am wondering, in what situation, should I implement a functionality as a standalone Shell script file or as a shell function?

Some of my thoughts: I know some graphical sessions (such as KDE, Gnome, etc.) source different files when login. It might cause some confusion if one wants to use the shell functions in a graphically launched applications (such as clicking icon to open emacs). But I prefer to implement as shell functions and pull them together into files, which I think is neat and well organized.

Any other ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use functions for things you're going to use often.  They take up memory and require parsing when the shell starts — parsing which is wasted if you never use the function.

Use scripts for things that take a long time, which you do seldom.  The per-invocation parsing time is negligible and the clarity that having the scripts separate brings is beneficial.

So, for backup scripts, I'd strongly recommend a script rather than a function.

Comment: The criteria seem very vague to me. I don't really see the clarity that a script brings. The resource a function takes is often negilible, isn't it?

Comment: They're a little vague, but if I'm not going to be using the code more than once an hour, it belongs in a script.  I use scripts for things I use far more frequently than that.  In fact, I have two functions in my shell, and one of those is because of a bug in the IT-provided `/etc/profile` (the bug: `unset pathmunge` doesn't remove a function; that needs to be `unset -f pathmunge`), and I didn't create the other either — I've not yet tracked its origin.  I use scripts all the time; I have hundreds of them in my $HOME/bin.  [...continued...]

Comment: [...continuation...] Don't get me wrong; there are times for using functions.  Many of my scripts include functions because they make it easier to write the script.  But I don't have much use for functions in my main login shell environment.

Comment: "Use functions for things you're going to use often"; "for backup I'd strongly recommend a script"; rsync hot up-to-date backup is one of the most frequently evoked utilities I can imagine of. That's a funny contradiction:D

Comment: How many times an hour do you run your backup function or script?  If the answer isn't many times an hour, I don't consider a function a worthwhile investment.

Comment: If you work on a file / set of files you may write changes each few seconds. Using `rsync -u` in co-operation with `crontab` you achieve a "hot" incremental backup which depending on needs may be set to be run several times a minute. And still one may wrap it in a function with another commands like logging, etc. (note you must use `@` when addressing non-author's comments, I have just noticed this after weeks by accidental browsing:)

Comment: @bloody — your backup requirements are wholly different from what I was considering. I don't do backups multiple times a minute; once a day would be more frequent than normal.  This is why you have to evaluate recommendations in light of your circumstances. There's nothing to stop you using as many functions as you like.  I find little or no use for them in my environment; you appear to have a reason to use them more heavily.

Comment: Those are not my requirements. That's how tools tailored for this work (e.g. google backup&sync). I almost don't use shell functions either, only pointed out the backup/frequency correlation which is high when you're working on files which reside in backup-monitored location.

Answer (score 1):

A python-like solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

caller_shlvl=$1
shift

backup () {
    ...
}

if (( $caller_shlvl < $SHLVL )); then
    backup "$@"
fi
```

You can do one of two things:

```
bash script.sh $SHLVL other args
```

to run the backup when you call the script, or

```
source script.sh $SHLVL
# Time passes
backup firstarg secondarg etc
```

which will define the function in the current shell but not execute it.

(Having to pass $SHLVL as the explicit first argument is the closest I could get to simulating Python's

```
if __name__=="__main__":
```

It's not pretty, and probably makes this answer not-so-useful.)

Comment: When you want to call `backup()` when the script is not sourced, you can use `(return 0 2>/dev/null) || backup`